# How to create a variable using another variable as an Index?

Tags: r

I'm looking to create a new variable, d, which grabs the value from either an or b based off of the variable C.

```
dat = data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=rep(1:2,5))
```

The result would be:

```
d = c(1,12,3,14,... etc)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `row/column` indexing where the row index is the sequence of rows and column index the 'c' column, `cbind` them and extract the elements from the dataset based on this

```
dat$d <- dat[1:2][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), dat$c)]
dat$d
#[1]  1 12  3 14  5 16  7 18  9 20
```

NOTE: This should also work when there are multiple column values to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
dat$d <- ifelse(dat$c==1,dat$a,dat$b)
```

Comment: thank you. though this works for the example, it is a simplified version of my problem. akrun's solution is generalizable to my case (20+ columns).

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` variant

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(d = case_when(c==1 ~ a, 
                       TRUE ~ b))
```